# How to add depth (volume) to order book plots?

Tags: limit-order-book, visualization

I wonder how one could plot bid/ask volumes along with the prices as shown below:

[image: figure_1]

Another example is:

[image]

To be more specific, I want to ask **how to plot volume for each price level as some sort of shaded area below/above the price line**.

I'm posting the question here because I believe people here are more familiar with the context and likely have already done something similar. It would be great if someone could drop a few lines of code or simply point me to which kind of plots I should go looking for.